# Filtering Messages

Tags: algorithms, strings

I saw this question posted and can't seem to find it for some reason, so I'm posting it again.

There's a leetcode problem that's asking for the number of possible strings that are alphabetically between 2 strings (`A` and `B`) of equal length such that string `C` is not a substring of any of the strings. How would you approach solving it?

I solved the trivial case where if `C.length = A.length` and `C` is lexographically not between `A` and `B`, the answer is just the number of possible strings between `A` and `B`. The problem is I don't understand how to solve the normal case where we try to calculate the number of strings that contain `C` by "growing" `C` (ie. adding characters on either end).

[image: problem statement] [image: problem statement continued]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  Don't copy-paste the entire thing; post only a summary or only the necessary part of a problem statement.

Comment: @D.W. - it is transcribed (the important bits). was this automated?